# Transition Matrix with Probabilities

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am given a problem which asks to find the transition matrix of the system.
the problem states:

> At any given time t,
>
> 1. a particle in box 1 is 5 times more likely to go to box 2 than to box 3;
> 2. a particle in box 2 is 6 times more likely to go to box 3 than to box 1;
> 3. a particle in box 3 has equal probability of going to either box 1 or 2.

Ao I constructed the 3 state vectors, one for each box respectively:

$$x_1(t) = 0 + \frac56 + \frac16\\
x_2(t) = \frac17 + 0 + \frac67\\
x_3(t) = \frac12 + \frac12 + 0 $$

Now, clearly once this is augumented into a matrix, the columns do *not* add up to $1$, so therefore the numbers are wrong.

I guess what I am having trouble with here is converting from "$n$ times more likely" to a probability. I have tried looking into other questions to see how they convert it but I cant find any.

Any suggestions or tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transition probability matrices, the rows have to add up to $1$, not the columns.  So, it looks like what you have is correct.  In matrix form:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&\frac56&\frac16\\ \frac17&0&\frac67\\ \frac12&\frac12&0
\end{array}\right)$$
As you can see, the sums of the rows all equal to $1$.

Comment: I am pretty sure its the columns that need to add up to 1, not the rows

Comment: It is up to you on how you define your vectors.  If you define your vectors as column vectors, then you must transpose the matrix above.  But if you are defining row vectors, then what I have is correct.  Anyways, by convention, we typically use right stochastic matrices to define transition probability matrices, which is the rows add up to $1$.